# LoganSquare parse into generic Object or Map

Tags: android, json

I'm using the very fast LoganSquare to parse JSON in Android.
I'd like to parse a JSON string into either a generic Object or preferably a Map.
For most cases I use custom object that map my json response, but in some cases the response is too generic and I'd rather just map it to a Hashmap for example.
Is that possible?
I tried various ways but it seems to fail.
Cheers.